# How to choose specific DbSet from context by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a bunch of DbSets that have the same structure so I can call them all as `MyObject`. In my EntityFramework I have a lot of entities that look the same, but have some other meaning. All entity types have 6 column/fields (the same).

Now, how can I choose the proper set from context basing only on DbSet name?

```
context.Set(Type type)
```

is not OK, because I can't call LINQ for Entities with it as long as I need a specific `DbSet<OneOfEntities>`.

Something missing?

**UPDATE:**

I've come up with idea of getting entities info by using reflecion but it seems to be a dead end as well, because still I can't determine from code the specific datatype for each of entities. Even when I have the table name, ex. `MyObject` and another `MyObject2`, `MyObject3`, etc. I can't transform it to the class which is defined in EDMX model. I tried something with `Type.GetType()` mixed with assemblies or by concatenating class name (table name) to namespace in one string. Still nothing.

Comment: Can you post your models and the db context?

Comment: I'll prepare some code tommorow if problem remains unresolved. Thank you for your engagement! For now I can only summarize it to say that I have multiple db tables that are actually the same and in fact they could be stored in just one table. Now, I want to prepare only one REST endpoint to manage them all but with some string discriminator coming from UI to controller, service, repository...

Comment: Can't you just do `context.OneOfEntities`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not really, because I have only db table name from UI and this name is also the name of one of entities. Anyway it is not possible to point dbset basing only on the class name when the entity is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic repository approach.  Check this example out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Basically, you have something like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal SchoolContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    //Other code
}
```

I have used this approach for years, and it works awesome!!  That way you are not tied to EF.  Remember, you have to wrap your classes so you don't get stuck on a framework.  The .NET Core EF is very different, and the upgrade would be very hard without a wrapper.

I noticed your comment about the entities having the same properties.  I would use an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
     //Add properties
}
```

Then make your entity inherit from this class:

```
public class MyExampleClass : EntityBase
{
     //Add other properties
}
```

Finally, change the GenericRepository to for TEntity to be a type of EntityBase:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    //Reference code from example
}
```

Comment: Hi, still, I have a problem because in my controller I call service that references to repository but I don't have the specific `DbSet<TEntity>` to offer. Where and how can I get this type having only class name as string?

Comment: If you must need a string, then you could utilize a dictionary. That said, I would set a generic type parameter in your controller and utilize this instead.  When I develop application, I put my business logic in a different application and not in my controller.  This makes it easier to transition from one framework to the next in the future.  If you need more info, please open up a chat with me.