# How to provide entity type/dbset type in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with a realisation of issue discussed in one of my previous thread ([How to choose specific DbSet from context by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960662/how-to-choose-specific-dbset-from-context-by-name)).
I have a class:

```
public class MyObjectRepository<TEntity> : MyObjectRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : MyObject
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;


 public MyObjectRepository(DbContext dbContext)
 {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
 }

public bool DoesRecordExist(string id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
           .Any(x => x.id == id);
    }
}
```

I also have a service class that have a repository field & executes operations like `DoesRecordExist(string id)`. I have few classes registered with EntityFramework (every of them refers to db table: MyEFClass and myEFANotherClass respectively) that look like that:

```
public partial class MyEFClass: MyObject
{
}

public partial class MyEFAnotherClass: MyObject
{
}
```

Classes are empty here because I use code-first & `MyObject` in fact has all fields of EF classes so the are empty & should be used only for navigation between db tables.

Now, how do I tell to context which DbSet is active. For example how to say to generic repository that I use `MyEFClass` or `MyEFAnotherClass`?
I belive it should be called from service.
I've been trying with `context.Set<something>()` and `something.GetType()` from assemblies but failed anyway.
At final moment I always have response that I use base class `MyObject` which is not a valid EF DbSet (just a base).

I would be happy to know your ideas or approaches.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue? You have generic repository, why do you need to do `context.Set<>()` on your service? You would just instantiate a new object of your generic as a type of your entity. Seems to be you don't have a strong understanding on generics.

Comment: when I send request to REST endpoint, it comes with the base type `MyObject` as `TEntity` while what I need (to point the proper DbSet and work with it) the specific type like `MyEFClass` or `MyEFAnotherClass` and the app crashes as long as `MyObject` isn't in fact an EF entity.

Comment: Your problem is now how to active the right repository type. Look at Activator.CreateInstance.

Comment: @GertArnold, I tried it, but still I have to specify type for DbSet<TEntity> and passing a type parameter here is simply a hell of an issue.
I only have a string with Entity name and I have to activate the proper repository basing on this string which is equal to db table/entity name

Comment: You can get the type by selecting it (by name) from the types in the assembly.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use "string" to determine your entity for your repository? You have a class defined why not use them? This is a huge design flaw, maintenance nightmare, and potentially break your application...

Comment: The reason is that user chooses the entity name from UI (dropdown list) and sends the string with request to controller

Comment: And yes, I have a method to choose proper type from assembly but still, I can assign it to variable which can't provide me something like this:
`DbSet<TypeVariable.GetType()>` or `DbSet<Type.GetType(TypeVariable)>`. I have to choose the proper DbSet from the service layer. otherwise I have a `DbSet<MyObject> which provides me clean access to properties but `MyObject` is just a base class and in DB I inly have `MyEFClass` & `MyEFAnotherClass` which provide access to db rows of each table.

Comment: Friends, do you think coming up with `switch` operator would be a nice approach? I would be able to determine `DbSet<someType>` and use it in repository. My switch discriminator would be the table/class name and switch would return a proper set. Please, verify this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have something you called a `service`, which has MyObjectReposistory as a field. The object repository has a DbContext as field.

This `service` has the notion of *active* MyObject. It knows whether MyEfClass or MyOtherEfClass is the active one.

This means that someone should tell your service which class is the active repository. Once this is done, whenever you'd like to do something with the active repository, we know which repository is meant.

Usually repositories are designed to hide the real internals of the database. Therefore I'd not expose the types of your tables to the users of your service.

Consider using an enum:

```
enum ActiveRepository
{
    MyEfClass,
    MyOtherEfClass,
}


class Service
{
    private MyEfClass myEfRepository = ...;
    private MyEfClass myOtherRepository = ...;
    public ActiveRepository ActiveRepository {get; set;}

    private IDbSet<MyObject> GetActiveRepository()
    {
       if (this.ActiveRepository == MyEfClass)
           return this.myEfRepository;
       else
           return this.myOtherEfRepository;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your post. I've come up with something like that and possibly this approach will remain the way to go.